# Single select with chosen with razor

Tags: razor, jquery-chosen

So i have implemented Chosen with my project and worked great with multi select but i want to add that for simple dropdown. I have total of 80 entry in dropdown so need the search function of chosen..this is my code.

```
<div class="editor-label">

                         <span style="color: red;">*</span> <strong>Select Therapist:</strong>
                     </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">

            @Html.DropDownList("TherapistList", Model.TherapistList

     , new

     {

         @class = "chzn-select",
         data_placeholder = "Choose  Therapist",


     }
     )
        </div>
```

and

```
<script >

    $(".chzn-select").chosen({
        allow_single_deselect: false,
        search_contains: false,
        no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });

</script>
```

i have addded the CSS and .JS reference on top. Its working fine with multiselet when i add   `@Html.ListBox("TherapistList", Model.TherapistList`

but i want single select with search option as they display on website.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't call @Html.Listbox but @Html.DropDown you will get a single select chosen.

```
@Html.DropDownList("TherapistList", Model.TherapistList, new {
     @class = "chzn-select",
     data_placeholder = "Choose  Therapist",
   }
)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! It worked, Forgot you accept your answer.